# How to redirect from '/' to '/en' in Amazon s3 with redirect roules

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

How can I redirect `/` and `/index.html` to `/en` in s3 static webhosting with redirect rules. I'm not using cloudfront or similar. The following rule does not work:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/en</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this with redirect rules, for a couple if reasons -- first, you've written the rule for a key prefix of `/`, but the leading slash is not considered part of the object key by S3.  The first character of an object key is the character *after* the leading `/`.  Removing that `/` would trigger a redirect loop for every object, because S3 would redirect every request regardless of the object, since that rule would match all of them.

Instead, modify index.html (the one in the root of the bucket) in the console, to add this metadata:

```
x-amz-website-redirect-location: /en/
```

This will redirect the browser, and the URL will show `/en/`, and the object stored in the bucket at `en/index.html` will be displayed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html